# sitecore asp.net membership password format

Tags: asp.net, sitecore

I have a sitecore membership provider that I have set up in my web.config.  I set the passwordformat on the web.config to clear.  This works on my local machine but when I put my changes onto a server the passwordformat is coming back as hashed.

This is my configuration in my web.config:

```
<membership defaultProvider="switcher" hashAlgorithmType="SHA1">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="Extranet" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="Extranet" applicationName="sitecore" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" requiresUniqueEmail="true" minRequiredPasswordLength="1" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordFormat="Clear" />
    <add name="sitecore" type="Sitecore.Security.SitecoreMembershipProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" realProviderName="sql" providerWildcard="%" raiseEvents="true" />
    <add name="sql" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="core" applicationName="sitecore" minRequiredPasswordLength="1" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="256" />
    <add name="switcher" type="Sitecore.Security.SwitchingMembershipProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" applicationName="sitecore" mappings="switchingProviders/membership" />
  </providers>
</membership>

<switchingProviders>
  <membership>
    <provider providerName="Extranet" storeFullNames="false" wildcard="%" domains="extranet" />
    <provider providerName="sql" storeFullNames="true" wildcard="%" domains="*" />
  </membership>
```

This works on all the developer machines but on the dev and production server environments the passwordFormat is hashed.  I should also mention that the dev and prod servers connect to dbs on different servers.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please provide your code for the related issue

Comment: And please change your code and password format to be encrypted. Never ever "clear"

Comment: @AliShahrokhi I have updated my question with my web.config configuration.

Comment: @MarkCassidy I can't change it to encrypted for internal reasons.  I know that it is the safest way but don't have a choice.

Comment: Have you checked the config in dev/prod servers are the same as this?

Comment: @jammykam the configs are the same